# ZFS list - root mounted twice?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, mount, root

I've followed [this guide](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS%20for%20Raspberry%20Pi.html) to install ubuntu with root on zfs. I've skipped creating all the dedicated (sub) datasets in step 3.3. Now "zfs list" looks like:

```
NAME                       USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                     1.94G   113G       96K  /
rpool/ROOT                1.93G   113G       96K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ynfa9e  1.93G   113G     1.93G  /
```

Now I am wondering why "/" is mounted twice... Is there anything wrong with my setup, or else what's the reason for this double mounting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a mountpoint set do not mean the dataset is mounted.

Try `zfs get mounted -r rpool`, and you’ll see that only `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ynfa9e` is mounted.

I do not have any sandbox right now, but I’ll be curious to see what happens if you unset the `root` mountpoint.

Comment: ah, thx! Indeed only `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ynfa9e` is mounted.